# JSON ID validation with default key:value pairs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json-ld

(language:javascript, backend: node.js)
Hi, I'm currently creating the web-application that receives url in a textarea and get JSON LD(<script type=“application/d+json”) form its website. These JSON LD are created following schema structure.

Here is what I want to do;
I would like to validate values in properties. For example, in @type="Article" of schema.org, thumbnailUrl property expects to receive URL. If thumbnailUrl has just a string (not url), this program should return an error. At first, I tried to use ajv package as a node package, but it looks like each schema of property needs to be written like this:

```js
var schema = {
  "$id": "http://example.com/schemas/schema.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": { "$ref": "defs.json#/definitions/int" },
    "bar": { "$ref": "defs.json#/definitions/str" }
  }
```

Writing these schema for everything is nearly impossible given the number of properties schema.org has. So, instead of writing down everything, I would like to use a package if it exits.

In this situation, is there any npm package I can use to validate the values of JSON LD?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `schemaorg-jsd`?

Comment: Or, try jsonld.js.